# Problem with caching in cloudFront (CDN- AWS), cache and collapse forward are acting the same

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

Users are sending requests for me for information, some times this info is personalized, and sometimes it's common to all. When it's common to all I want the CDN to cache the answer. I distinguish between the users by query params.

The problem - The problem is when I want them to stop using the cache, and each to get their personalized content.

I thought that if I'll send the response with cache flag off (max-age = 0) the user's requests won't use the cache, the requests would come to me, and I would give them their personalized answer.
But the CDN in that case doing collapse forwarding and all the users continue getting not personalized answers.

I didn't found a way to disable the collapse forwarding, and I couldn't find a way to continue serving the client personally after they start using the cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: I highly doubt collapse forwarding is the issue here. Request collapsing will merge concurrent requests to your origin in the event of a cache miss. If your issue was caused by collapse forwarding it would occur only for concurrent requests. I think what's happening is your response gets cached at the edge and subsequent requests are never reaching your origin because they are served from the Cloudfront cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and chatting with support (detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69455222/2223706)).  It turns out that you can't stop CloudFront from sending non-personalized results just by using the `Cache-Control` header.  Instead you have to have separate "Behaviors" and namely a `CachingDisabled` behavior for routes where you need personalized responses.