# RefreshHit from cloudfront even with cache-control: max-age=0, no-store

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

Cloudfront is getting a RefreshHit for a request that is not supposed to be cached at all.

[image]

It shouldn't be cached because:

1. It has `cache-control: max-age=0, no-store`;
2. The Minimum TTL is 0; and
3. I've created multiple invalidations (on `/*`) so this cached resource isn't from some historical deploy

[image]

Any idea why I'm getting RefreshHits?

I also tried modifying Cache-Control to be `cache-control no-store, stale-if-error=0`, creating a new invalidation on `/*` and now I'm seeing a cache hit (this time in Firefox):

[image]

Comment: That page suggests enabling "Use Origin Cache Headers" which sounds exactly like what we would need, but that setting appears to only be available if we use their "Legacy cache settings" option on our Behavior, but we're using the new "Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)" option.

Comment: No, because I need it to cache some requests from my origin, but not others, so I really need it to base its caching off of the `Cache-Control` directive that the origin gives it.  (the use-case is not so relevant, but it has to do with a piecewise migration of our whole site from jQuery to Next.js)

Comment: Yeah, it's bit a strange use-case.  We're currently transitioning our website one page at a time from a non-cacheable, backend-rendered jinja2/jQuery to a cacheable, client-side rendered React/Next.js.  It would be really nice if we could have behavior controlling all ~100 pages such that when one is transitioned to Next.js, it automatically starts getting cached.  It's only during the transition where we have this use-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After talking extensively with support, they explained what's going on.

So, if you have `no-store` and a Minimum TTL of 0, then CloudFront will indeed not store your resources.  However, if your Origin is taking a long time to respond (so likely under heavy load), while CloudFront waits for the response to the request, if it gets another identical request (identical with respect to the cache key), then it'll send the one response to both requests.  This is in order to lighten the load on the server.  (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-traffic-spikes))

Support was calling these "collapse hits" although I don't see that in the docs.

So, it seems you can't have a single Behavior serving some pages that must have a unique response per request while serving other pages that are cached.  Support said:

> I just confirmed that, with min TTL 0 and cache-control: no-store, we cannot disable collapse hit. If you do need to fully disable cloudfront cache, you can use cache policy CachingDisabled

We'll be making a behavior for every path prefix that we need caching on.  It seems there was no better way than this for our use-case (transitioning our website one page at a time from a non-cacheable, backend-rendered jinja2/jQuery to a cacheable, client-side rendered React/Next.js).

Comment: That is good to know (regarding behaviour under load).  As for the cache control I think you want set the cache control on the origin to `max-age=0, must-revalidate, public` and make sure you can also sending back an etag

Comment: Garrett thanks for emphasizing the collapse hits concept @Cory I've tested your suggestion: adding the max-age=0, must-revalidate, public or even private directives 
didn't do the trick, meaning - The 2nd invocation returns the cached response from the 1st request

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for OP's project, but I would personally handle this with a simple origin-response Lambda@Edge function, and a single cache behavior for /* and cache policy. You can write all of the filtering/caching logic in the origin-response function. That way you only manage one bit of function code in one place, instead of a bunch of individual cache behaviors (and possibly a bunch of cache policies).

For example, an origin-response function that looks for a cache-control response header coming from your origin. If it exists, pass it back to the client. However if it doesn't exist (or if you want to overwrite it with something else) then you can create the response header there. The edge doesn't care if the cache-control header came from your origin, or from an origin-response Lambda. To the edge, it is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Another trick** you can use in order to avoid caching and still use the default CloudFront behavior, is: Have a dummy unused query parameter that equals to a unique value for each request.

**Python example:**

```
import requests
import uuid
requests.get(f'http://my-test-server-x.com/my/path?nochace={uuid.uuid4()}')
requests.get(f'http://my-test-server-x.com/my/path?nochace={uuid.uuid4()}')
```

Note that both calls will reach destination and will not get response from cache since the `uuid.uuid4()` will always generate a unique value

This works since by default (if not defined otherwise in the Behavior section) the query parameters are part of the cache key

Note: Doing so will avoid cache use, hence your backend might be loaded with requests.